# How to track youtube video in AMP pages

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, amp-html

I have implemented GTM in my webpages, when user plays video GTM tracks logs for normal web pages, But i dont know how to implement for AMP pages.

Can someone explain it how to write scripts for AMP page video

Comment: You can get started by checking out tutorials like [Accelerated Mobile Pages Via Google Tag Manager](https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/accelerated-mobile-pages-via-google-tag-manager/#3-create-and-implement-gtm-amp-container) and How to [Use Google’s Tag Manager on Accelerated Mobile Pages](https://www.advancedwebranking.com/blog/how-to-use-googles-tag-manager-on-accelerated-mobile-pages/).

Comment: Looking for the same; there is very little documentation available on this topic.